# Extract incomplete RAR archive under linux (desktop)

Tags: rar

I have many not compressed rar multi-part archives on my ftp server.

Under Windows, with 7zip I have no problem with extracting part1 when I have not downloaded part2 from server yet. There is notification about errors, but if some files were complete in part1 - they extract correctly and I can use these files.

Under linux - looks like there is 7zip with rar non-free module (I think 7z was installed when I was installing Gnome).

How can I extract my files from incomplete multi-part archive under Linux?

I'm using Debian 7 (amd64 architecture) with Gnome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `unrar`, you have the switch `-kb` (“keep broken)”, which doesn't erase the extracted files even when there are errors.

Comment: I found similar way with Midnight Commander and unrar. Is there any way to do it in Gnome, or I have to open console every time?

Comment: If you use file-roller, as this program searches the path for a unrar executable, you could make a stub script that calls the real unrar and trick it.